# C# Validacion numero de telefono

Tags: c#, regex

he probado con distintas expresiones regulares y no me ha funcionado ninguna este es mi codigo no se si tiene algun error del cual no me he dado cuenta, solo quiero que el numero tenga entre 7 y 10 digitos. 
Gracias de antemano

```
 static string LeerNumero(string msg)
    {
        string error = "", numero = "";
        Regex Val = new Regex(@"\A[0-9]{7,10}\z");
        while(!(Val.IsMatch(numero)))
        {
            Console.Write("{0}{1}", error, msg);
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            if (numero.CompareTo(String.Empty) == 0)
                error = "Error.";
        }
        return numero;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Gonzalo Bienvenido a stack overflow en espa**ñ**ol, primero que todo, **por que piensas que existe un error ?.**

Este algoritmo podria tener ciertos problemas a mi forma de verlo y ya que no lo has especificado te dejo algunas ideas.

1) la mas clara el `Console.Write("{0}{1}", error, msg);` que se encuentra en tu codigo se esta imprimiendo siempre es decir cada vez que se ejecuta el `while` se imprime esta linea con el mensaje que recibio el metodo `LeerNumero` y el error que al parecer siempre es una cadena vacia.

2) si la validacion `if (numero.CompareTo(String.Empty) == 0)` intenta comprobar si el numero que ingreso el usuario por **consola** en la linea `numero = Console.ReadLine();` esta vacio, entonces supongo que es aqui donde debe ir el **write** del error.

```
if (numero.CompareTo(String.Empty) == 0){
    error = "Error.";
    Console.Write("{0} {1}",error,msg);
}
```

3) Y sobre la expresion regular lo que dices lo puedo entender de esta forma cuando **( <=7 o >7 y <=10 )**.

```
^(\d{7,10}|\d{10,10})$ ------ ( <=7 o >7 y <=10 )
```

> SI quieres experimentar y probar otras opciones [aqui](https://www.regextester.com/99401) te dejo una pagina muy buena para hacer pruebas de expresiones regulares

De cualquier forma **deberias aclarar el ¿por que? piensas que esta generando un error** y tal vez **que resultado esperas realmente**.

En cualquier caso te dejo una solucion a los puntos anteriores (con el ejemplo de 
  **( <=7 o >7 y <=10 )**).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(LeerNumero("mensaje generico?"));
    }

    static string LeerNumero(string msg) {
        string error = "", numero = "";
        Regex Val = new Regex("^(\\d{7,10}|\\d{10,10})$");

        while(!Val.IsMatch(numero)) {
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            if (numero.CompareTo(String.Empty) == 0){
                error = "Error.";
                Console.Write("{0} {1}",error,msg);
            }
        }
        return numero;
    }
}
```

Asi que existen varias respuestas posibles dependiendo de lo que ingrese el usuario.

- Cuando el usuario no ingresa nada (presiona !ENTER!)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Cuando ingresa un numero invalido **(<7 o >10)** (repite el while, en este punto se puede añadir el **write** del  error que supongo intentabas imprimir para numeros errados)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Cuando el numero es correcto **( <=7 o >7 y <=10 )**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto

```
public class ExpRegTelefono
{
    public static bool Validar(string telefono)
    {
        Regex exreg = new Regex("^\\d{7,10}$");
        return exreg.IsMatch(telefono);
    }
}
```

Con `\d` buscas número `{7,10}` de longitud y que empiecen `^` y terminen `$` exactamente. No se si me he explicado.